# How to use Hölder inequality to prove this integral inequality?

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, harmonic-analysis, holder-inequality, fubini-tonelli-theorems

Consider an integral operator $Tf(x)=\int_{\mathbf{R}^n}K(x,y)f(y)dy.$ And $s,r \in(0,\infty), s \geq r$ are two indices. I would like to prove
\begin{equation}
\| Tf\|_{r} \leq   (\int_{\mathbf{R}^n}  \int_{\mathbf{R}^n} |K(x,y)|^rdx)^{s/r}dy) ^{1/s} \| f \|_{s'} 
\end{equation}
(Assume all the integral are not infinity, and $\| f \|_r$ stands for the standard $L^r$ norm, that is $(\int_{\mathbf{R}^n} |f(x)|^r dx)^{1/r}.$)

Since on the right hand side, the term of $K$ first integrate to x then to y, my attempt is to use Fubini theorem and  Hölder inequality,
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
| Tf(x) | &\leq \int_{\mathbf{R}^n} | K(x,y)| |f(y)| dy \\
&=\int_{\mathbf{R}^n} | K(x,y)| |f(y)|^{1/r} |f(y)|^{1/r'} dy \\
& \leq (\int_{\mathbf{R}^n} | K(x,y)|^r|f(y)| dy)^{1/r} (\int_{\mathbf{R}^n} |f(y)| dy)^{1/r'} \\
Then \quad \int_{\mathbf{R}^n} | Tf(x) |^r dx &\leq \int_{\mathbf{R}^n}(\int_{\mathbf{R}^n} | K(x,y)|^r|f(y)| dy) (\int_{\mathbf{R}^n} |f(y)| dy)^{r/r'} dx
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
Another attempt is to use Hölder plus Minkowski's inequality
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\| Tf \|_r&=(\int_{\mathbf{R}^n}|\int_{\mathbf{R}^n} K(x,y)f(y)dy|^r dx)^{1/r} \\
&\leq (\int_{\mathbf{R}^n}|\int_{\mathbf{R}^n} |K(x,y)|^sdy|^{r/s} dx)^{1/r} (\int_{\mathbf{R}^n} |f(y)|^{s'} dy)^{1/s'} \\
But \ s \geq q, \ Minkowski \ cannot \ get \ the \ desired \ outcome.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
I am stuck at it.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

Right, you do want to apply Fubini, then Hölder, but after that, to bring the power r inside the x-integral, you’ll need to apply Minkowski’s integral inequality as well.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes, we indeed have $s \geq r$(I forgot to type it). I will try your advice.

Comment: I am still stuck, could you explain this to me more explicitly? (I have renewed some details in the question)

Comment: Sorry, forget about Fubini. You should have proven Minkowski Integral Inequality, see en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_inequality. Write out \|Tf\|_r, apply Minkowski, then the result follows immediately from Hölder with exponents s,s’.